# Showing a set is open but not closed

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $X = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x > 0, y \geq 0 \} $. I am claiming $X$ is open, but it is not closed.

My Try:

To show it is not closed, I found a sequence that converges to a point outside $X$. For instance, $(x_n, y_n) = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} ) \to (0,0) \notin X$. Hence, $X$ cannot be closed.

In trying to show it is open, I have diffictulty trying to find a suitable open ball contained in $X$. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture; this set is the first quadrant in the plane, together with the ray $$\{(x, y) : y = 0, x \ge 0\}$$

Any ball whose center has $y$-coordinate zero will intersect the lower half-plane, and so cannot be contained in the set; hence it's not open.

---

Morally, the set contains a little bit of its boundary, which causes it to be non-open.

Comment: thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The set is not open. Take for example the point $P=(5,0)$. There is no ball with centre $P$ which is fully contained in our set.

Comment: thanks. I understant. My argument to show that the set is not closed is correct?

Comment: Yes, your argument that it is not closed is correct.